# Use columns from table using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have data

```
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:36],"CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443",200 0,"SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 13C75) Safari/601.1",9443 api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com 443 1856
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:36],"CONNECT init.itunes.apple.com:443",200 0,"MobileSafari/601.1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0",9443 init.itunes.apple.com 443 50073
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:54],"GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/getnewsfeed/?",304 292,"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1",9443 www.rbc.ru 80 9547
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:56],"GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/mainjson/?",200 99535,"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1",9443 www.rbc.ru 80 0
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:58],"CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443",200 0,"SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 13C75) Safari/601.1",9443 api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com 443 40633
```

I use code to give names

```
colnames = ["used_at", "url", "smth", "browser", "smth2"]
df = pd.read_csv("urls.csv", names=colnames, delimiter=",", header=None)
```

when I do this I try `print df['url']`, but it print, that it's NAN.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I find your previous post where is link to your [data](https://yadi.sk/i/NnT7q2I_rf3Jn).

So you can use `sep='""'` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), but then is neccessary [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for removing `"` in first and last column:

```
import pandas as pd

colnames = ["used_at", "url", "smth", "browser", "smth2"]
df = pd.read_csv('test/file1.csv', names=colnames, header=None, sep='""', engine="python")

df['used_at'] = df['used_at'].str.strip('"')
df['smth2'] = df['smth2'].str.strip('"')

print df.head()
                                            used_at  \
0  213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:52 +0300]    
1  213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:52 +0300]    
2  213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:52 +0300]    
3  213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300]    
4  213.87.147.105 - - [25/Apr/2016:17:42:53 +0300]    

                                                 url         smth  \
0                    GET http://www.livejournal.com/   200 37306    
1  GET http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activ...     200 601    
2  GET http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activ...     200 601    
3  GET http://rtax.criteo.com/delivery/rta/rta.js...    200 2996    
4  GET http://l-stat.livejournal.net/tmpl/??Widge...    200 1256    

                                             browser  smth2  
0  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Bu...   9445  
1  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Bu...   9445  
2  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Bu...   9445  
3  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Bu...   9445  
4  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920F Bu...   9445
```

For me it works very nice (`delimiter=","` can be omited, because separator in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has default value `,` ):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:36],"CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443",200 0,"SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 13C75) Safari/601.1",9443 api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com 443 1856
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:36],"CONNECT init.itunes.apple.com:443",200 0,"MobileSafari/601.1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0",9443 init.itunes.apple.com 443 50073
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:54],"GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/getnewsfeed/?",304 292,"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1",9443 www.rbc.ru 80 9547
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:56],"GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/mainjson/?",200 99535,"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1",9443 www.rbc.ru 80 0
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:58],"CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443",200 0,"SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 13C75) Safari/601.1",9443 api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com 443 40633"""
```

```
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
colnames = ["used_at", "url", "smth", "browser", "smth2"]
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), names=colnames, header=None)
print df
                                    used_at  \
0  213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:36]   
1  213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:36]   
2  213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:54]   
3  213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:56]   
4  213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:58]   

                                        url       smth  \
0   CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443      200 0   
1         CONNECT init.itunes.apple.com:443      200 0   
2  GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/getnewsfeed/?    304 292   
3     GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/mainjson/?  200 99535   
4   CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443      200 0   

                                             browser  \
0  SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS...   
1  MobileSafari/601.1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15...   
2  Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Ma...   
3  Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Ma...   
4  SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS...   

                                        smth2  
0   9443 api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com 443 1856  
1        9443 init.itunes.apple.com 443 50073  
2                     9443 www.rbc.ru 80 9547  
3                        9443 www.rbc.ru 80 0  
4  9443 api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com 443 40633
```

```
print df['url']
0     CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443
1           CONNECT init.itunes.apple.com:443
2    GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/getnewsfeed/?
3       GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/mainjson/?
4     CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443
Name: url, dtype: object
```

Comment: Works just fine for me too.